# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './node_modules/core-js/fn/promise' vue cli

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-extension, vue-cli-5

I am using vue to write a chrome extension.I initialize my project through `vue-cli-plugiin-chrome-extension`.
I use `promise` in my `background.js`.When i run `npm run build-watch`,it throw the erro like this

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './node_modules/core-js/fn/promise' in 'C:\Users\COD002\OneDrive\桌面\vue-test\test\src\entry'

(node:12064) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Build failed with errors.
    at Watching.handler (C:\Users\COD002\OneDrive\桌面\vue-test\test\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\commands\build\index.js:207:23)
    at C:\Users\COD002\OneDrive\桌面\vue-test\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:290:9
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\COD002\OneDrive\桌面\vue-test\test\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:24:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (C:\Users\COD002\OneDrive\桌面\vue-test\test\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at Watching._done (C:\Users\COD002\OneDrive\桌面\vue-test\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:287:28)
    at C:\Users\COD002\OneDrive\桌面\vue-test\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:209:21
    at Compiler.emitRecords (C:\Users\COD002\OneDrive\桌面\vue-test\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:919:5)
    at C:\Users\COD002\OneDrive\桌面\vue-test\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:187:22
    at C:\Users\COD002\OneDrive\桌面\vue-test\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:885:14
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\COD002\OneDrive\桌面\vue-test\test\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:12064) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:12064) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have tried update `core-js` and download the whole `node_modules`again.But it doesn't work.
My package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "build-watch": "vue-cli-service  --env.NODE_ENV=development build-watch --mode development"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.2.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.12",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "vue-cli-plugin-chrome-extension-cli": "~1.1.4"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true,
      "webextensions": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this problem myself by chance. I deleted the `node_modules` folder again and ran `npm install`. It was warning me that `Prototype Pollution in async`, so I
followed guidance to fix it. Then the program didn't throw the error.